# Can anybody explain the structure of the Apache server?

Tags: apache

How does the Apache web server work? Can someone explain it in detail?

Comment: Is http://httpd.apache.org/ down?  Is the source repository unavailable?

Comment: Can you refine your question a bit?  You seem to be looking for something, but your question is too vague to give anything more useful then just pointing you at the docs/svn.

Comment: I also want to know the architecture of Apache HTTP server,but the "Apache architecture overview " link is dead.who can give some new stuff about Apache 2?

Answer (score 6):

Start with the [Apache architecture overview](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~tve/cs290i-sp01/papers/Concept_Apache_Arch.htm) to understand the basic components and data flows for Apache. Then, you probably want to go into the [developer documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/developer/), as the list module configuration options in the docs is not too helpful in understanding how does everything work.

Finally, comparing Apache to other popular open-source servers such as [Lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net) would show you what tasks are approached in a similar way by different programs, and where there are trade-offs (speed vs. features, for example) that differentiate between the servers.

Answer (score 3):

It's magic. Don't even bother trying understand it.